# Reading from text files in Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net, file, file-handling

This is the first challenge on Day 1 of the 2018 Advent of Code
(link: https://adventofcode.com/2018/day/1)

So I am trying to create a program that reads a long list of positive and negative numbers (e.g +1, -2, +3, etc.) and then add them up to create a total. I have researched some methods of file handling in Visual Basic, and have come up with the below method:

```
    Sub Main()
        Dim objStreamReader As StreamReader
        Dim strLine As String = ""
        Dim total As Double = 0
        objStreamReader = New StreamReader(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory & "frequencies.txt")
        strLine = objStreamReader.ReadLine
        Do While Not strLine Is Nothing
            Console.WriteLine(strLine)
            strLine = objStreamReader.ReadLine
            total += strLine
        Loop
        Console.WriteLine(total)
        objStreamReader.Close()
        Console.ReadLine()
    End Sub
```

Here is a link to the list of numbers: https://adventofcode.com/2018/day/1/input

It is not a syntax error I am getting but a logic error. The answer is somehow wrong, but I cannot seem to figure out where! I have tried to remove the signs from each number but that throws me a NullException error when it compiles.

So far I have come out with the answer 549, which the Advent of Code webiste rejects. Any ideas?

Comment: A NullReferenceException occurs at runtime, not at compile time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make your life easier by using `File.ReadLines(fileName)` instead of dealing with `StreamReader`. Use `Path.Combine` instead of string concatenation to create a path. `Path.Combine` takes care of adding missing `\` or removing extra ones etc.

Your file might contain an extra empty line at its end, that does not convert to a number. Use `Double.TryParse` to make sure you have a valid number before totalizing it. You should have `Option Strict On` anyway to enforce explicit conversions.

```
Dim fileName = Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "frequencies.txt")
Dim total As Double = 0
For Each strLine As String In File.ReadLines(fileName)
    Console.WriteLine(strLine)
    Dim n As Double
    If Double.TryParse(strLine, n) Then
        total += n
    End If
Next
Console.WriteLine(total)
Console.ReadLine()
```

Answer (score 1):

For appending two string, please use string builder.
Dim test as new stringbuilder()
Test.append("your string")
It will not affect performance.